# How to add Bootstrap jQuery to WordPress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am learning WordPress and am transferring a basic bootstrap template to Wordpress so I can them edit it, but I can't get the jQuery to work.

I have this code saved in my functions.php file in my theme folder.

```
 <?php

function test_resources() {

wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap.min.js', get_template_directory_uri(). 'js/bootstrap.min.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery.easing.min.js', get_template_directory_uri(). 'js/jquery.easing.min.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
wp_enqueue_script( 'scrolling-nav.js', get_template_directory_uri(). 'js/scrolling-nav.js', array( 'jquery' ) );

}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'test_resources');
```

Comment: Just do a simple Google search: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-bootstrap-css/

Comment: You need jquery by itself and it needs to be called before bootstrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a slash before the path '/js/bootstrap.min.js'

function test_resources() {

wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap.min.js', get_template_directory_uri(). '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array( 'jquery' ) );

wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery.easing.min.js', get_template_directory_uri(). '/js/jquery.easing.min.js', array( 'jquery' ) );

wp_enqueue_script( 'scrolling-nav.js', get_template_directory_uri(). '/js/scrolling-nav.js', array( 'jquery' ) );

}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'test_resources');

Comment: yeah all it needed was a slash before the path. Thanks a million, feel like an idiot not seeing that, just needed fresh eyes to see it because I was staring at it for too long.

Comment: Yeah :) Happened to me couple of times, that's how I've noticed. No problem.

Answer (score 2):

You have to call the jQuery yourself using this.

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
```